# jquery hover animation queuing

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, queue

I'm having problems working with jquery's animation function when hovering over and out of a div.

What i'm trying to do is when the mouse hovers over the element, it enlarges it. This works fine but the problem occurs when you move the mouse over it quite quickly, so I guess what's happening is the animation hasn't finished and it keeps queuing the hover.

I have included an example of my work on the JSFiddle link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/hPeHG/

Answer (score 1):

You should use [.stop(true)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to clear the queue before you add the new animation.

```
$('selector').stop(true).fadeOut(...);
```

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't have any effect. There is no change in the functionality.

Comment: The difference is that your boxes won´t continue to grow when you trigger the event mutiple times raidly.

Comment: I just tried .stop(true, true) and that worked fine with the completed boolean flag I just put in.